# How to delete inspection profiles in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-inspections

I'm unable to delete inspection profiles in IntelliJ. I can choose one of my custom profiles and click on the "Delete ..." menu item. This removes it from the Profile drop down list.

If I click "Ok" at the dialog window and then open it again all deleted profiles are still there.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? Can you please share the idea.log (Help | Show Log in Finder) after the profile is "deleted". As the workaround: you may delete profile manually from configuration directory/<product><version>/inspection folder (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory)